# Mathematica Not Seeing All CPU Cores

Tags: parallelization, hardware

I have a machine with 112 CPU cores, but $ProcessorCount reports only 32 cores. Windows 11 sees all 112 cores, and other applications are able to use them, but Mathematica only sees 32. Any idea how to address this? CPUs are dual 56-core Xeons.

Comment: You might check your license configuration.  You might need a Mathematica Core Extension license.

Comment: See: https://support.wolfram.com/27860?src=mathematica

Comment: Good thinking. Unfortunately, this machine is on a network license that allows for unlimited kernels. Other machines on the license can use more than 32. In fact, I can manually launch 112 kernels, but it still sees and uses only 32 processor cores.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica counts physical cores only, not the multiply threaded ones reported by the task manager (the number, that in real time does not count really for  a single user machines computing tasks in the second/minute range without pausing).

Type ResourceMonitor into the search Box or open it in TaskManager (Ctrl+Alt+Del).

In Menu/Help/SystemInformation/Parallel

you see, how many physical kernels are registered.

Comment: As stated in my original post, I have 112 physical CPU cores. It would be 224 if we were counting hyperthreading. $ProcessorCount reports the same information as in SystemInformation/Parallel. Mathematica only sees 32 cores, which is not even a logical fraction of 112, hence why it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Windows reports threaded numbers as I wrote. The physical number for Mathematica is a license issue. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+many++cores+mathematica+does+support+maximally. So its a question for your system provider, if you are using a net license, that typically shares the the total number purchased for the user pool, currently online. We used to go online at late night for maximal access.

Comment: The license this machine is on is unlimited, and $MaxLicenseProcesses confirms that. So that is not the source of the 32-core limitation.

Comment: Does not make any sense, physical core is just an implementation detail: for all purposes there are two or 4 cores in each physical core.

Comment: @Zoid, the kernel doesn't understand processor groups on Windows.  As such, Windows will cap the logical processor count for the process to 64.  Seeing that `$ProcessorCount`  ignores SMT, that is how the result can end up as 32.